# Convert a form into PDF with the input fields

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, jspdf

I have managed to convert my HTML document into PDF using the jsPDF library by MrRio. the problem is my content is a form. The pdf file shows the field names but I am unable to get their input.

```
<div id="editor">
    <form id="content" class="text-center border border-light p-5" action="" method="POST">
        <!-- Full Name -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Full Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFullName" placeholder="Full Name" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Adress -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Adress</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAdress" placeholder="Adress" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- E-mail -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Password -->
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
$(function () {
    var specialElementHandlers = {
        '#editor': function (element,renderer) {
            return true;
        }
    };

    $('#cmd').click(function () {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.fromHTML(
            $('#content').html(), 15, 15, 
            { 'width': 170, 'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers }, 
            function(){ doc.save('sample-file.pdf'); }
        );
});
```

I need to get the form with the user input.

I have tried the HTML to canvas and then to pdf and then I tried this. Apparently, there are limitations to the implementation of this method as it doesn't support many elements or classes. If anyone could provide insights or useful help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by querying the values introduced by the user either by using jquery or pure javascript.

This is a snippet of the solution:

```
<button id="cmd" class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" type="submit" onclick=" $(function () { 
   var doc = new jsPDF()
   doc.text('Full Name: \t\t\t'+document.querySelector(`#inputFullName`).value, 10, 10)
   doc.text('Adresse: \t\t\t'+document.querySelector(`#inputAdress`).value, 10, 20)
   //here do the same for the rest of your inputs
   doc.save('a4.pdf')
        });">Send</button>
<button class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" type="reset">Reset</button>
```